# Access denied in ajax call only existing on IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I encounter this problem when using Xmlhttprequest to do ajax call. I test the code on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, they all work well. Only the problem existing on IE, my used version is 9.
Some guys say I should enable the cross domain support. Actually, I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * into 
http response header.  Any ideas? Thanks.

My code is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var query = queryString.pageName.abbr + "="
        + encodeURIComponent(queryString.pageName.value) + "&"
        + queryString.pageURL.abbr + "="
        + encodeURIComponent(queryString.pageURL.value);
var getURL = "http://localhost:10001/test?" + query;

xhr.open('GET', getURL, false);
var result;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var responseBody;
    if (xhr.readyState == 2) { // headers and status received
        alert(xhr.status);
    } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // full body received
        result = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: You should be using something like jQuery to abstract this spaghetti

Comment: @Joseph, it should also work when using XMLHttpRequest. I update the question with the solution.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  What is the domain of the page executing this script?  Why not just use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Here someone with the same problems: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/17449/xmlhttprequest-not-working-in-ie9/p1.
Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060.
I would also recommend, like the others, to use jQuery. They think about those problems: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283